# How can I loop through a non determined JSON key and send a message with it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I made a command which registers pokémon you are shiny hunting for, how many you have got, and how many eggs it took/is taking for you to get the shiny, and it works fine. My problem is that some people forget the pokémon they did register in that storage, and so I would like to be able to send a message containing all the pokémon they registered in the Storage, like this:

```
You have registered the following pokémon:  
(All the pokémon you registered)
```

But, I don't know how to loop through the keys that are inside of the user's ID. Here's how my json file looks:

```
{
    "User's ID": {
        "Pokémon": {
            "encounters": value,
            "shinies": value
        },
        "Pokémon": {
            "encounters": value,
            "shinies": value
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried looping like this:

```
 const path = require('path');
 const fs = require('fs');

 const shiniesDataPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './Storage/shiniesData.json');

 function loadShiniesData() {
     return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(shiniesDataPath).toString());
 }

 const shiniesData = loadShiniesData();

 var trainer = shiniesData[message.author.id];

 if (args[0] === 'all') {
     for (var trainer in shiniesData) {
         message.channel.send([trainer])
     }
     return;
 }
```

But it only loops through the ID's.

Comment: `let encounter, shinies; for(let s of shiniesData){ for(let o of s){ encounter = o.encounter; shinies = o.shinies; } }` Note that you would have to use those variables within the loop.

Comment: What I know can be done is ```You have registered the following pokémon: Pikachu        
Fennekin```, but I would like it if it were ```You have registered the folowing pokemon: Pikachu, Fenekin```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the example code that you have provided is not entirely clear.
like what do you have var trainer in two places.

```js
var trainer = shiniesData[message.author.id];

 if (args[0] === 'all') {
     for (var trainer in shiniesData) {
         message.channel.send([trainer])
     }
     return;
 }
```

I am guessing this what you are looking for

```js
if (args[0] === 'all') {
    Object.keys(shiniesData).forEach(userId => {
        const monsterNames = Object.keys(shiniesData[userId]);
        message.channel.send(userId, monsterNames]);
    });
    return;
}
```

Comment: ```message.channel.send(monsterNames);``` was the solution, but thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

A JSON object should not have multiple identical keys, rather what you can do is assign the `Pokémon` key to an `array`, like this:

```
{
    "User's ID": {
        "Pokémon": [
            {
                "encounters": value,
                "shinies": value
            },
            {
                "encounters": value,
                "shinies": value
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In order to access the keys, let's say the object above was assigned to variable `obj`. In order to access the keys in an object, you can do

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    // Do something
})
```

However if you switch to an array as I have done, I'd imagine you would want to do something like this instead:

```
obj['Pokémon'].forEach((item) => {
    // Do something
})
```

where `obj['Pokémon']` returns the array mapped to the key 'Pokémon', and `.foreach` iterates through each item in the array, and you can access it within the anonymous function (surrounded by curly braces) via the variable `item`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const message = {
    author: {
        id: "1234"
    },
    channel: {
        send: console.log
    }
}

// stubbed function
function loadShiniesData() {
    return {
        "1234": {
            "Pikachu": {
                "encounters": 2,
                "shinies": 3
            },
            "Fenekin": {
                "encounters": 5,
                "shinies": 1
            }
        }
    }
}

const shiniesData = loadShiniesData();

const trainer = shiniesData[message.author.id];

message.channel.send('You have registered the following pokemon:\n' + Object.keys(trainer).join(", "));
```

Once you've retrieved the users data then you can use `Object.keys` to get an array of the pokemon names.